# how to dynamically change html table single column 60 rows to three column 20 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to seperate a dynamically loaded 60 rows single column html table to three column 20 rows using jquery in jsp.

example i Have a loaded table like this

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
test 6
test 7
test 8
test 9
test 10
```

i want to convert it like below with jquery

```
test 1    test 5    test 8
test 2    test 6    test 9
test 3    test 7    test 10
test 4
```

code from

```
<div class="ui-jqdialog-content ui-widget-content" id="editcntgrid">
<span>
<form style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: auto;" onsubmit="return false;" class="FormGrid" id="FrmGrid_grid" name="FormPost">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="EditTable" id="TblGrid_grid">
<tbody>
<tr><td>test 1</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test1" name="test1" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 2</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test2" name="test2" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 3</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test3" name="test3" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 4</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test4" name="test4" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 5</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test5" name="test5" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 6</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test6" name="test6" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 7</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test7" name="test7" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 8</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test8" name="test8" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 9</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test9" name="test9" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 10</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test10" name="test10" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</span>
</div>
```

code to be dynamically converted to below using jquery, making this into 3 columns,and need to have a flexibility to make to 4 columns if i have more rows.

```
<div class="ui-jqdialog-content ui-widget-content" id="editcntgrid">
<span>
<form style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: auto;" onsubmit="return false;" class="FormGrid" id="FrmGrid_grid" name="FormPost">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="EditTable" id="TblGrid_grid">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>test 1</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test1" name="test1" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 2</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test2" name="test2" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 3</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test3" name="test3" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 4</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test4" name="test4" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td>test 5</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test5" name="test5" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 6</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test6" name="test6" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 7</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test7" name="test7" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table>
    <tr><td>test 8</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test8" name="test8" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>test 9</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test9" name="test9" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
<tr><td>test 10</td><td><input type="text" size="3" id="test10" name="test10" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</span>
</div>
```

can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not able to modify the how the table is initially built with Java? That would be the better way to handle this. If not, here's my way to do it with jQuery:

Dynamic # of columns: http://jsfiddle.net/nWdtq/5/

2 column (as coded below): http://jsfiddle.net/UhKLm/3/ :

```
var rows = $('#table_id tr').length;  // Number of rows in original table
var half = Math.ceil(rows/2);         // Number of rows needed
var remove = half+1;                  // Remove any rows after the halfway point

// Loop through all the rows
for(var x = 1; x <= rows; x++){

    // Find the child to go into the second column
    var second_ele = x + half;

    // If you half way and there is an odd number of entries
    if (x == half && rows % 2 != 0){
        continue;
    }
    // Find the row with the data for the second column (half + x)
    // and append the html to the current row's html
    else if (x <= half){
        $('#table_id tr:nth-child('+x+')').html(
            $('#table_id tr:nth-child('+x+')').html()+$('#table_id tr:nth-child('+second_ele+')').html()
        )
    }
    // Any entries after half way are already in the second column, remove them.
    else{
        $('#table_id tr:nth-child('+remove+')').remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Birdman it worked well , how to make this code work if i need three columns with all the rows. Since i have (random)61 rows i am trying to fit it to screen size by making it into 3 columns of 20 each.

Comment: @Bhas This is a start [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWdtq/5/). It's a little buggy when you start to add more columns. B/c I'm rounding up and truncating off the last col, you might end up with no entries in the last column. I'll see if I can get back to this and fix it up some more, but I'm at work... shhhhhh

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, Yes you are right it is missing few rows when i tested with 60 rows. when you find free time at later point can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure I'll help. That's why we're here. It'll be about 4 or 5 hours before I get a change to address this though. For clarification, when you have 17 entries across 4 columns, did you want the last column to be short by 3 or the last 3 columns short by 1?

Comment: Sure thanks, i have tested again, the code you have provided is working fine. But the problem is i have first three rows with style display: none;<tr style="display:none ;"> so when i change the table with jquery the table rows are wrapped and the top three row columns disappeared because of the style, i want to ignore the hidden rows and start with the one which is not hidden or display as none, so i could able to view all the columns after rearranged(first three rows). Let me know if i have conveyed my issue properly.

Comment: Seeing how you're hiding them, do you still require the information in those fields? If you don't then just add
`$('#table_id tr[display=none]').each().remove();`
as the first line of the script I provided. That should remove them so they don't interfere with the table reorganization.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Multicolum tutorial:

http://www.webkrauts.de/2011/12/08/css-3-im-praxistest-multi-column-layout/

I had the same issue i did it by this css:

```
.text_split {   
-webkit-column-count: 2;   
-webkit-column-gap: 50px;   
-moz-column-count: 2;  
-moz-column-gap: 50px;  
-o-column-count: 2;   
-o-column-gap: 50px;  
column-count: 2;   
column-gap: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i was trying to do through jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark

```
var tdArray = new array();
$('.tdclass').each(function(){
  tdArray.push($(this).html());   
});

$('#tablid').html('');
var i = 0;
$.each(tdArray,function(index,value){
  if(i == 0){
    $('#tableid').append(<tr>)
  }
  $('#tableid').append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
  if(i == 1){
    i = 0;
    $('#tableid').append('</tr>);
  }
  i++;
});
```